# Sequelize - Include all children if any one matches

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js

I have two entities, Post and Tag, I am trying to query for all posts that have any one tag passed to the where clause. In addition, I want to include ALL the tags for the final set of Posts.

The association is defined as so

```
Post.belongsToMany(
      models.tag,
      {
        through: 'post_tag'
      }
    );
```

My query is like so

```
models.post.findAll({
    limit: 20,
    offset: 0,
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'name'
    ],
    include: [{
        model: models.tag,
        attributes: ['name'],
        where: {
            name: {
                [Op.in]: ['tagNameHere']
            }
        }
    }],
    where: [{
      active: {
        [Op.not]: 'False'
      }
    }],
    order: [ ['name', 'ASC'] ]
})
```

It does work, but the included tags array is ONLY that one specified within the Op.in. I want ALL the tags to be included

Any better way of going about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach is to make two passes: 1) find posts that have particular tag, 2) find all tags for those posts.   You need a third association to make this happen:

```
models.post.belongsToMany(models.tag, {through: models.postTag, foreignKey: 'post_id'} );
models.tag.belongsToMany (models.post,{through: models.postTag, foreignKey: 'tag_id' });

models.post.hasOne(Post, {
   foreignKey: {name: 'id'},
   as: 'selfJoin'
});
```

Now, identify posts that have particular tag (or tags)

```
models.post.addScope('hasParticularTag',
{
   attributes: ['id'],
   include: [
     {
       model: models.tag, 
       through: models.postTag,
       attributes: [],
       where: {name: 'TAG-YOU-WANT'}   // your parameter here...
     }]    
 });
```

Finally, list selected posts and all their tasks...

```
models.post.findAll({    
   attributes: ['id','name'],
   include: [
      { // ALL tags
        model: models.tag, 
        through: models.postTag,
        attributes: ['name']
      },
      { // SELECTED posts
        model: models.post.scope('hasParticularTag'),
        required: true,
        as: 'selfJoin',   // prevents error "post isn't related to post"
        attributes: []
      }]
 })
```

HTH....

Comment: I added the self join association to Post, and updated the query to have an include on that new self association, which has an include on Tag with a where clause. 

include: [{
    model: models.tag,
    attributes: ['name']
}, {
    model: models.post,
    required: true,
    as: 'selfJoin',
    include: [{
        model: model.tag,
        where: {
            name: {
                [Op.in]: ['tagNameHere']
            }
        }
    }]
}]

But now I have an issue where the limit isn't being applied correctly.

Comment: What's the problem with LIMIT?  It looked OK to me (though you need `attributes['id']` for selfJoin to fix a SQL error)

Comment: LIMIT works, the SQL it generate looks right as well. However, when there is more than one tag, they get grouped and that's when the limit returned varies.